# Extract audio from mp4 video using command line

Tags: command-line, multimedia

Is there any command to extract audio from mp4 video?

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy -map a OUTPUT.m4a` work?

Comment: Thanks.
It does work.
Is there anyway to output mp3 format?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -b:a 256k -map a OUTPUT.mp3`

Comment: @guest Do you know why the output audio file average bitrate is always 128 kbps and if it's possible to preserve the audio bitrate at all?
BTW, you could write this as an answer not to leave the queation unanswered, and also earn points. ;-)